# Filter nearest date interval

Tags: r, dplyr

I was wondering is there were a simple way to filter a dataset to only keep records for nearest intervals.

**My data looks like this:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)    
df <- data.frame(country = rep(c("Spain","Portugal"), each = 4), 
                     type = rep(c("1","2"), each = 4), 
                     name = rep(c("A","B"), each = 4), 
                     event_start = as.Date(c("2012-07-13", "2014-09-05", "2016-12-23", "2017-01-01", "2015-11-27", "2014-06-27", "2013-04-11", "2012-11-27")), 
                     event_end = as.Date(c("2014-09-04", "2016-12-22", "2016-12-31", "2017-01-09", "2016-02-10", "2014-11-26", "2014-06-26", "2013-04-10")), 
                     start = rep(as.Date(c("2008-10-01", "2017-01-01")), each = 4),
                     end = rep(as.Date(c("2008-12-31", "2017-12-31")), each = 4),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      mutate(event_interval = interval(event_start, event_end),
             int = interval(start, end))
```

**Expected result:**

```
country type name, event_start, event_end, start, end, event_interval, int
Spain 1 A 2012-07-13 2014-09-04 2008-10-01 2008-12-31 2012-07-13 UTC--2014-09-04 UTC 2008-10-01 UTC--2008-12-31 UTC
Portugal 2 B 2015-11-27 2016-02-10 2017-01-01 2017-12-31 2015-11-27 UTC--2016-02-10 UTC 2017-01-01 UTC--2017-12-31 UTC
```

In essence, I would like to keep — for each combination of `country`/`type`/`name` — the row for which `event_interval` is the nearest to `int`.

I've tried (and kind of succeeded) with a not-so-good-looking `for loop` but was wondering if you knew of something more straightforward with `dplyr`?

Cheers

**EDIT**
To clarify, in the example above, `event_int` and `int` don't intersect, but this is not always true in my entire, proper dataset. In fact, for many  combinations of `country`/`type`/`name`, there may be several `event_int` overlapping with `int`, so I really need to find which `event_int` is the most similar to `int`, i.e. the `event_int` that overlaps the most with `int` OR is the nearest to `int`.

Comment: How do you define "nearest"?

Comment: The `event_int` that overlaps the most with `int` OR is the nearest to `int`

Comment: If your interval is `2019-01-01 to 2019-01-02` and you are going to choose the nearest interval from `2018-01-01 to 2018-12-31` and `2019-01-03 to 2019-12-31`, which one is closer?

Comment: What package is the interval() function from?

Comment: Sorry @Bill O'Brien, I forgot to include the packages. I edited the post

Comment: @Mako212, the overlapping one is, for my purpose, more important. If it would be easier to separate instances where both types of intervals overlap, and instances where they don't, that's OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I figured it out. Asking my question really helped me clarify what I wanted to do, and I then found [R / lubridate: Calculate number of overlapping days between two periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224879/r-lubridate-calculate-number-of-overlapping-days-between-two-periods).

The following bit of code does what I need:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(ndays = pmax(pmin(end, event_end) - pmax(start, event_start) + 1, pmax(pmin(end, event_end) - pmax(start, event_start) + 1))) %>%
  group_by(country, type, name) %>%
  arrange(country, type, name, desc(ndays)) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1) #Keeps nearest or most overlapping record
```